# Track google analytics code

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-analytics-api

I am trying to link my local data to Google's Analytic data. For example, if I add java script code that maps the click of my register button on my website. I would like to get the id/result of that insertion. I would then like to save this id along with my user object. This way I could map my registration events to my users and in the future analyze this data.

Is this possible? If so any ideas how it would be done? I have had a look at the api docs and my first thought was that the function ga() should return something, I do not believe that it does? My next thought was that I could post an id or data to Google that I post to my server on user creation.

Any ideas or suggestions would be more than appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you asking for [Web Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)?